# Centralize deployment/environment properties using Spring Config Server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I have 2 microservices(Xservice, springcloudconfigserver service) implemented in Springboot.  Springcloudconfigserver service exposes all the application properties and deployment properties in json format. Xservice shall be deployed in CloudFoundry/kubernetes environment(uses deployment.yamls /manifest.yaml for deployments). Xservice has bootstrap.properties which is configured to use the configserver uri

Now my problem is , I would like to have the environment variables(instances,memory setting for each environment, database settings) provided by configserver service injected into XService yaml files  during the build process of Xservice ?

At this point the application shall be already be deployed.  How can I achieve this using spring, spring boot, spring cloud config,jenkins? whats the best way to approach to this problem.